How can I store a list of initializers in c++?
I'm trying to make a function to initialize different classes that all have the same base class. To find which class to initialize, there will be an enum passed in the function. The only way I can do this without using a large switch statement is to have a list of all the initializers. How can I do this?

Can you use a std::map?

Since you don't know how to do this, how do you know you can do it this way (much less it being the only way)?

A code snippet for this question might include stub definitions for a base class, two derived classes, and your enumeration, plus a declaration of your desired function. And it might be useful to show us the function defined with a large switch statement so that we have a way to confirm that answers have the same functionality. (Put // And many more cases... after the cases for the two derived classes to remind people that it is longer in practice.) Or maybe show us the "list of all the initializers" as a starting point.

Personally, I would use the map technique described by @Çınar Aydemir . But I should mention that the switch version has advantages in that the compiler will warn you about missing options if you add new values to the enum later.

You can achieve this by using a map to store function pointers or std::function objects that create instances of your classes. This way, you avoid a large switch statement. Here’s an example to illustrate this:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void print() const = 0; // Pure virtual function
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    void print() const override {
        std::cout << "Derived1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    void print() const override {
        std::cout << "Derived2" << std::endl;
    }
};

enum class Type {
    Derived1,
    Derived2
};

// Factory functions
std::unique_ptr<Base> createDerived1() {
    return std::make_unique<Derived1>();
}

std::unique_ptr<Base> createDerived2() {
    return std::make_unique<Derived2>();
}

// Map to store factory functions
std::map<Type, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>()>> initializerMap = {
    { Type::Derived1, createDerived1 },
    { Type::Derived2, createDerived2 }
};

std::unique_ptr<Base> createObject(Type type) {
    return initializerMap.at(type)();
}

int main() {
    auto obj1 = createObject(Type::Derived1);
    obj1->print(); // Output: Derived1

    auto obj2 = createObject(Type::Derived2);
    obj2->print(); // Output: Derived2

    return 0;
}

In this example, we define a base class Base and two derived classes Derived1 and Derived2. We use an enum Type to identify the classes. We then create factory functions for each derived class and store them in a map initializerMap. The createObject function takes a Type and uses the map to call the appropriate factory function, returning a std::unique_ptr.
This approach helps keep your code clean and extensible without needing a large switch statement.

Small nitpick - you can make initializerMap hold function pointers instead of std::function objects. Using std::function is overkill unless you need to use stateful lambdas for your creators. Plain functions and state-less lambdas can be used with function pointers.

Not sure I agree with @RemyLebeau. I always want to go with the most readable form first (which I think std::function provides). I will go with function pointers only if there is an absolute need for more performance (space/time). But this is just a personal preference. If I got a version with function pointers in a code review I would not complain.
